# embed fonts when using addPlot to a pptx

Tags: reporters

I am on RHEL6 using addPlot (with vector.graphic=TRUE) to add a plot to a pptx document. I can specify the various fonts via the fontname_mono (etc.) arguments. For example, on my system one of the monospace fonts available is "Nimbus Mono L". However it seems this font is not available in my windows installation of powerpoint, and consequently it renders using some other (non-monospace) font. Is there any way for ReporteRs to "embed" the requested fonts so that the resulting pptx will be portable in this regard?

Note: while setting vector.graphic=FALSE does result in properly rendered fonts, this is not the solution I am hoping for.

Fundamentally, I suspect the question is really about rvg::dml_pptx since it is doing the heavy lifting...I get the same result whether or not I use ReporteRs::addPlot as the front-end.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can embed fonts in a PPTX, the following article is explaining how:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826832/how-to-embed-fonts-in-powerpoint